# Best way to unpublish a node, given the nid, while bypassing any node update hooks?

Tags: 7, nodes, location

To unpublish a node, I set status=0 and call node_save(). Unfortunately, this invokes the Geocoder module and it sends a request to the Google API for a geocode that I already have. There is apparently no way to turn this off.

I am looking for an alternative to node_save() that does not trigger this behavior or any other hooks, for that matter.

(btw, for fields I am achieving this with field_attach_update, but to unpublish I need to update the node itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an array of nids you could just run this piece of code

example will unpublish the nodes with nid 1,2,3:

```
$nids = array(1, 2 ,3);

foreach($nids as $nid) {
    db_query("UPDATE {node} SET `status` = '0' WHERE `nid` =:nid ;"
,array(':nid'=> $nid));
}

entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache($nids);
```

Comment: That won't clear the relevant caches...

Comment: Clive, I updated my code to clear the relevant caches, good call!

Comment: Nice :) For a performance gain, you could take it out of the loop and run `entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache($nids);` directly

Comment: good call (again), i'll update the code